# Is it customary to initialize Groovy variables to default values?

Tags: groovy

```
def someVar
String stringVar
int intVar
boolean boolVar
```

vs

```
def someVar = null
String stringVar = null
int intVar = 0
boolean boolVar = false
```

I looked at quite a few Groovy coding conventions but I wasn't able to find any recommendations

**UPDATE** Just to emphasize - I am asking about conventions and not about Groovy language requirements. It is clear to me that above code snippets yield the same result.

Comment: Depends on your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

groovy based on java

and in java each type has predefined default value:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

- `byte`, the default value is `zero`, that is, the value of (byte)0.
- `short`, the default value is `zero`, that is, the value of (short)0.
- `int`, the default value is `zero`, that is, 0.
- `long`, the default value is `zero`, that is, 0L.
- `float`, the default value is positive `zero`, that is, 0.0f.
- `double`, the default value is positive `zero`, that is, 0.0d.
- `char`, the default value is the null character, that is, `\u0000`.
- `boolean`, the default value is `false`.
- for all reference types, the default value is `null`.

even groovy converts all simple types to reference types, the rules above still true

but beware - all reference types - `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, ... will be initialized with `null`:

```
byte b
Byte B

assert b==0
assert B==null
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am asking about conventions and not Groovy language requirements.